# fastboot serial number?

Tags: adb, fastboot

On occasion I've seen the serial number reported by `adb` and `fastboot` differ. Is there a way to reliably determine what the `fastboot` serial number will be from `adb`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the serial number as reported by `adb get-serialno` **will** be different to fastboot as determined by:

- Manufacturer
- Make and model of device in question
- Android version

`fastboot`, on the other hand, since there's no `adb` loaded, instead, it uses a rudimentary USB protocol tied in with the boot-loader, the serial number will be different.

> Is there a way to reliably determine what the `fastboot` serial number
>   will be from `adb`?

There is no reliable way of achieving it.

Comment: Just to be thorough, not even `adb shell cat /some/file`?